# How to use DBRefs to fetch records from multiple collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am working on a database for library system. I have a collection called 'books' and another collection called 'publishers'.

This is my documents structure in collection 'book'.

```
{
  "_id" : 1.0000000000000000,
  "book_name" : "C++",
  "book_details" : "This is book details"
},
{
  "_id" : 2.0000000000000000,
  "book_name" : "PHP",
  "book_details" : "This is book details"
},
{
  "_id" : 3.0000000000000000,
  "book_name" : "JAVA",
  "book_details" : "This is book details"
}
```

This is my documents structure in collection 'pulishers'.

```
{
    "_id" : 1.0000000000000000,
    "pub_name" : "Sky Publishers",
    "pub_details" : "This is publisher details",
    "published_books" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "books",
            "$id" : 1.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "$ref" : "books",
            "$id" : 2.0000000000000000
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, my question is how to write a query in mongodb to show books details which are published by this publisher.